# DynaTree ContextMenu Copy/Paste not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, dynatree

I'm having an issue with DynaTree which is a jQuery plugin that allows me to generate a tree view from an unordered list. The problem is that I tried to implement a context menu with it just like the one [here](http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/samples.html) and no matter what I do, the line:

```
var node = $.ui.dynatree.getNode(el);
```

Refuses to work properly, meaning that no matter what, the node object is always null when I look at it through the "inspect element" view of chrome. I'm wondering if someone has had this issue before if they can help me. Thanks.

Alternatively if anyone knows how to select or at least get the data from the element that I just right clicked on/have my mouse over, that would work fairly well too. Thanks a bunch, in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you had a look at
    http://wwwendt.de/tech/dynatree/doc/sample-contextmenu.html

`el` should be a DOM element as could be obtained by event.target or is passed by your context menu's callback handler.